# How to get the value in front of a specified value from Series

Tags: pandas

```
xSeries = pd.Series([1,200,5,13,3,301],index=['b', 's', 'h', 'd', 'e','a'])
```

When i was given the value 13,i want to get the value 200 before the value 13.How do i write the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the value 2 rows before a known value. In this case, the known value is 13.

```
v = 13
xSeries = pd.Series([1,200,5,13,3,301],index=['b', 's', 'h', 'd', 'e','a'])
print(xSeries)
b      1
s    200
h      5
d     13
e      3
a    301
dtype: int64    

idx = xSeries[xSeries == v].index
print(idx)
Index(['d'], dtype='object')

a = xSeries.index.get_loc(idx[0])
print(a)
3
print(xSeries.iloc[[a - 2]])
s    200
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest approach I know is dropping down to numpy and letting it do the search natively:

```py
import numpy as np

xSeries[np.argwhere(xSeries.values==v).reshape(-1)[0]-1]
```

That returns correct values for all unique values `v` of xSeries. The previous value of 1 would be 301, as the search wraps around. 
This will raise `IndexError` if the value you search for isn't in the list, which is more or less appropriate.

Value search isn't well-defined; if you have more than one instance of a value, this search can't tell which one you meant. It will always find just the first instance. But thanks to numpy, it is nicely fast. About 50μsec in your small series, or about 15x faster than the fastest pure-Pandas solution I've seen.

Here's a cleaned up version that illustrates also how to set a boundary case for the first element so the search doesn't wrap around (should you wish it not to).

```py
def prev_value(series, v):
    posn = np.argwhere(series.values==v).reshape(-1)[0]-1
    if posn >= 0:
        return series[posn]
    return None
```

You'd call it with something like:

```py
prev_value(xSeries, 200)
```

Comment: @inaMinute Please consider up-voting answers that were helpful to you, and/or marking one of them as "the preferred answer" (by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer).